# Numerical solution to some functional equation

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, numerical-integration

Let $z>0$ be fixed. Consider the function $p_a: \mathbb R^2_+\to\mathbb R_+$ given as
$$
p_a(t,x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi N_a(t)}}\left[\exp\left(-\frac{(x-z)^2}{2N_a(t)}\right)-\exp\left(-\frac{(x+z)^2}{2N_a(t)}\right)\right],
$$
where $N_a:\mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R_+$ is defined by

$$N_a(t):=\int_0^t\frac{ds}{(1+a(s))^2}$$

and $a:\mathbb R_+\to [0,1]$ is some measurable function. I can show there exists a unique function $a^*$ (which is also decreasing) to the equation

$$a^*(t)=\int_0^\infty p_{a^*}(t,x)dx\equiv \text{Erf}\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{2N_{a^*}(t)}}\right),\quad \forall t>0,$$

where $\text{Erf}$ is the Gauss error function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). Is there (efficient) numerical scheme to compute/approximate $a^*$?

Comment: your defining equation for $a^\ast(t)$ could be written more compactly as $$a^\ast(t)=\text{Erf}\,\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{2N_{a^\ast}(t)}}\right).$$

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thanks for the comment which definitively simplifies the equation

Comment: your equation for $N_a(t)$ contains $a$ in the integration limit and in the integrand; how should I understand this? are these different objects?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Many thx for pointing out this typo. It is indeed $0$ instead of $a$

Comment: How is the function $a$ given? There are "some measurable function" which are awful for numeric approximation. And what precision do you need? What means "efficiency" to you?

Comment: @gg I can prove that $a^*$ exists, is unique and decreasing and Holder continuous. So we can simply say the space is continuous and decreasing. Here "efficiency" means that this scheme is implementable.  Indeed, the first method appearing in my brain is the fixed point iteration, while but I don't know how to implement it and control the corresponding error. Moreover, it seems costly for me to compute $Erf$

Comment: @Fawen90 : You said: "I can prove that $a^*$ exists, is unique and decreasing and Holder continuous". Can you share this proof with us somehow?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Of course, while I'm not sure whether this violates the rules of MO. Let me first write the reasoning in this comment : 1. First let us show the existence/uniqueness. Let $C^T_+$ be the space of continuous and non-increasing functions $a$ on $[0,T]$ taking values in $[0,1]$. Then it is clearly a closed subset of the Banach space (the space of continuous functions on $[0,T]$). Define the operator $\Gamma$ on $C^T_+$ that maps $a\in C^T_+$ to the r.h.s. the equation above. By definition $\Gamma: C^T_+\to C^T_+$. Then it suffices to show to the unique fixed point of $\Gamma$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis By computation, we may show that $\Gamma$ is a contraction map when $T$ is small (indeed the Lipschitz constant of $\Gamma$ is proportional to $z^2/t exp(-z^2/t)$). So the existence and uniqueness follow. 2. As $\Gamma: C^T_+\to C^T_+$, the unique fixed point must be non-increasing. 3. Finally, the Holder continuity also follows from the equation, where it is implied by the r.h.s. of the equation.

Comment: @IosifPinelis If my argument is not clear, I will post it later following my question

Comment: @Fawen90 : Thank you for your response. But you said that $a$ takes values in $[1,2]$. So, no solutions, in fact? Leaving that alone, you seem to have shown the existence and uniqueness only for small enough $T$. What about larger values of $T$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Many thx for pointing out my second typo. For the global existence/uniqueness, we may write $\mathbb R_+=[0,T]\cup [T,2T]\cup [2T,3T]\cup \cdots$, and do the same reasoning (for a slightly different $\Gamma$), and then paste the functions defined on each interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\erf{\operatorname{erf}}\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$The functional equation in question is
\begin{equation*}
    a=F(a) \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
on $(0,\infty)$, where $a$ is in the closed convex set, say $A$, of all nonincreasing functions from $(0,\infty)$ to $[0,1]$ with norm $\|\cdot\|:=\|\cdot\|_\infty$ and
\begin{equation*}
    F(a)(t):=\erf\frac{z}{\sqrt{2N_a(t)}} 
\end{equation*}
for real $t>0$.

For any $a\in A$, any function $h$ from $[0,\infty)$ to $\R$ such that $a+uh\in A$ for all small enough $u>0$, and all such $u$, let $g_{a,h}(u):=F(a+uh)$. Then for all real $t>0$
\begin{equation*}
g'_{a,h}(0+):=\lim_{u\downarrow0}\frac{g_{a,h}(u)-g_{a,h}(0)}u \\ 
=\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\,\exp\Big(-\frac{z^2}{2N_a(t)}\Big)
\frac{-z}{2\sqrt2\,N_a(t)^{3/2}} \int_0^t\frac{-2ds\,h(s)}{(1+a(s))^3}
\end{equation*}
and $\big|\int_0^t\frac{-2ds\,h(s)}{(1+a(s))^3}\big|\le2N_a(t)\|h\|$,
so that, with $y:=\frac z{\sqrt{2\,N_a(t)}}>0$
\begin{equation*}
|g'_{a,h}(0+)|\le\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\,e^{-y^2}y\,\|h\|\le r\|h\|, 
\end{equation*}
where $r:=\sqrt{\frac2{\pi e}}\in(0,1)$.
So, the map $F$ is a contraction. So, there is a unique solution $a^*\in A$ of \eqref{1}, and the iterations $a_{n+1}=F(a_n)$ with any $a_0\in A$ converge to $a_*$ uniformly on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Many thx Iosif for this strengthen proof that ensures the wellposedness of iteration on any interval $[0,T]$. Now fix any horizon $T>0$, and let us focus on the numerical solution on $[0,T]$. Taking $a_0\equiv 0$, set $a_{n+1}:=F(a_n)$. From the computational viewpoint, we pick, for each $n\ge 1$, a division of the interval $\{0=t^n_0<t^n_1<\cdots<t^n_{N_n}=T\}$ and suppose we obtain the approximating values of $a_n$ on the points $\{t^n_0,t^n_1,\ldots, t^n_{N_n}\}$. According to which criterion we should choose $\{0=t^{n+1}_0<t^{n+1}_1<\cdots<t^{n+1}_{N_{n+1}}=T\}$ (for $n+1$)?

Comment: More precisely, computer can stock at each iteration a finite number of values for $a_n$ (w.r.t. some grid $\{0=t^n_0<t^n_1<\cdots<t^n_{N_n}=T\}$), and how can we use this grid for the next step? Here we should also deal with the numerical integral to approximate $N_a$

Comment: To make the iteration implementable, an error analysis for $\tilde a_n-a_n$ is needed, where $\tilde a_n$ stands for the numerical approximation (that can be stocked in computer)

Comment: @Fawen90 : I think the questions about the $t^n_j$'s are important, but they should be posted separately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will post it separately